# Sveltekit using Static adapter fails when I try to have pages using Fetch to load dynamic data

Tags: fetch-api, sveltekit

So I can build "normal" static site without trying to load any dynamic data from my API.
But when I try this:

```
//export const prerender = true;

export const load = async ({ fetch }) => {
    const res = await fetch(`/api/WeatherForecast/`);

    if(res.ok){
        const weatherForecasts = await res.json();
        return { weatherForecasts };
    }

    const { message } = await res.json();

    return {
        error: new Error(message)
    };
}
```

I get the following error:[image]

Yeah. My code has to be prerendered. Fine. I got ahead and uncomment my code for pre rendering like so:

```
export const prerender = true;

export const load = async ({ fetch }) => {
    const res = await fetch(`/api/WeatherForecast/`);

    if(res.ok){
        const weatherForecasts = await res.json();
        return { weatherForecasts };
    }

    const { message } = await res.json();

    return {
        error: new Error(message)
    };
}
```

Now I get a json error and error 500 for my page like so:

[image]

[image]

How would I solve this problem? I did when that find if I made my Static site adapter to none strict:

```
adapter: adapter({assets: 'build', pages: 'build', precompress: false, strict: false})
```

It would simply ignore the http error and just build the site. When built it would work with my API and all is good. But somehow it feels "wrong".

What is the proper way of building a static site with Sveltekit and have some pages call API routes for data?

Comment: Struggling with kit behavior as well. So you're using adapter-static and able to fetch data? Then when you use npm run build, it compile the site? Is the data stored in your static files?

Comment: If it does work then it is not wrong. It works.

Comment: It is worth considering if a relative path will work at build time? How does vite know the full url for an environment it doesn't know about etc?